# Laptop shut off during upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

I was upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 on my laptop when the battery died.  Now when I boot into it, I can get to the login screen.  After I type my password, the screen appears to load but then I am sent back to the login screen with no error message or anything.

Do I have to reinstall?  Is there anyway to easily recover my data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the same problem, but the return-to-login problem happened to me in the past because a corruptes .XAutority file, so you could try to force its regeneration by running in a tty (you can get there by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F6):

```
sudo rm -vf .Xauthority
```

If you're not confident this is the problem, try first to log-in with the guest account. If it works, it means the problem is in your personal configuration. Once you reach the desktop you can try to find out if the upgrade finished properly.